# Calling java code from Apache Derby

Tags: sql, netbeans, jar, classpath, derby

I've written a simple method in Java:

```
package com.fidel.extensions;

public class Extensions {
    public static String capitalize(String input) {
        return input.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

I then registered it as a function in Apache Derby.

```
create function capitalize(inputString varchar(255))
returns varchar(255)
parameter style JAVA
no sql language JAVA
external name 'com.fidel.extensions.Extensions.capitalize'
```

In order to give the database access to that code, [this](https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines) page suggests I have two choices:

1. Install the jar into the database
2. Add the jar to CLASSPATH

This is the text from that article:

> The compiled Java for a procedure (or function) may be stored in the
>   database using the standard SQL procedure SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR or may be
>   stored outside the database in the class path of the application.

If I use the INSTALL_JAR approach to embed the jar into the database, my queries work fine. For example:

```
select capitalize('hello') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

However I don't actually want to store the jar in the database. I would like derby to look in my CLASSPATH variable to find it.

So I've added it to my CLASSPATH using the following:

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/home/fidel/dev/DbExtensions/extensions.jar
```

But when I run the same query, I get this error message:

> The class 'com.fidel.extensions.Extensions' does not exist or is
>   inaccessible.

I'm using Netbean's [SQL editor](https://netbeans.org/images_www/v7/3/features/ide-database-full.png), which I assume would pick up the CLASSPATH I've set.

Has anyone managed to reference code in an external jar, via the CLASSPATH?

ps. I know I can use the UCASE/UPPER methods. But the code above is just an example

pps. I am able to get the query to work by adding the jar to the Driver list, but I don't think that's the correct thing to do.

> Services -> Drivers -> Java DB (Embedded) -> Customize -> Add

Comment: According to the error message in your question, you specified 'Extension', not 'Extensions'. But later in your question you said you actually got your query to work. So maybe I don't know what your actual question is. Are you asking about how to manage the CLASSPATH for your program?

Comment: Thanks Bryan, it was a typo. My question is how to get the referenced jar to work in the Netbeans SQL editor (The doco seems to give the impression that just adding it to the classpath is fine)

Comment: Derby is happy to look in your CLASSPATH; I think NetBeans is making it a challenge for you to control your CLASSPATH for the SQL editor. I think your solution of putting your jar in the drivers list is perfectly fine, actually.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. You're right, when using the ij tool, Derby is happy to look in the CLASSPATH. I'll stick with adding it to the drivers list for now.